# Создание дополнительный базданных в обход GlassFish i ConnectionPool

Tags: glassfish, j2ee

Подскажите пожалуйста с таким вопросом. Могу ли я приконектитса к серверу Mysql без указания базы (это нужно для того, чтоб была возможность послать серверу запрос на создание новой базы на сервере), в обход ConnectionPool'a и других примудростей которые придлагает веб-контейнер.

```
Connection connection;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("https://exsample.com:3306/", "root", "xxx");
    System.out.println("CONNECTION: " + connection);
```

При выполнении данного кода вылетает следующая ошибка

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for https://exsample.com:3306/
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
```

При использовании ConnectionPool'a к конкретной базе - проблем нету :)

Или подскажите как єто можно решить другим способом. 
Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `https://exsample.com:3306/` нужно использовать `jdbc:mysql://exsample.com:3306/`